# how to run a java web app on a server provided by hoast monster

Tags: java, spring, maven, web-hosting

i have created a java Spring/Maven web app and have exported it as a war file. My friend has a server provided by [Host Monster](http://www.hostmonster.com/%E2%80%8E)
and is allowing me to use it to test my app. However, i cannot get it to work. it works fine on tomcat and jetty. any help on this matter is much appreciated. So What i need to know is

1. can i run a java app on a host monster server??
2. can i run a war file on a host monster server??
3. how do i publish my project to a host monster server??

Many thanks 
Billy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use **Openshift** as it´s easy to configure and free.

Those are the hosting option for **Java** applications:

> https://www.openshift.com/developers/java

I said that it´s easier to publish because you get a **GIT** repo when you create you App instance, you just have to checkout, add your project files there, commit and you app will publish automatically.

Here you´ve got a quickstart gide for **Spring + Openshift** combo:

> https://github.com/openshift/spring-eap6-quickstart

This service is based on **Amazons EC2** instances that you can configure later on if you want for scalability.

There are some cartridges that add functionality to you server instance. Like MySQL, MongoDB, ...

If I'm not mistaken you can configure up to 2 cartridges for each App instance.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: thanx for the reply yes this has solved my problem

Comment: sorry still a noob at this lol how do i accept the answer??

Comment: You´ve done it ;) thanks a lot!